# Network Manager not working after restart

Tags: networking, network-manager

I Attempted to restart Network Manager because the wifi connection kept going in and out despite it working on other devices, but when I did the Network Manager crashed. When I opened the Network Manager a window saying this opened

> The System Network services are not compatible with this version

And all the networking options were gone.

I ran:

`systemctl status NetworkManager.service`

but I got failed to start network manager. I don't know what went wrong and am unsure what to do next.